# Swipe and moving page conflicting events

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, swipe

In my web application there is an image gallery that uses swipe events to navigate to the next or previous pictures.

If a user zooms in to a particular image and tries to swipe to go to the next or previous picture, the whole page moves in addition to the swipe event being triggered, which creates a bad user experience. Note, this is a non issue, as long as the user is zoomed out all the way, however, I wouldn't want to limit the user in that way.

I was wondering if someone ever experienced this problem and has any suggestion as to how to troubleshoot this?

Swipe Event

```
$('.slideshowFrame').swipeleft(function () {
    galleryIndex = ++galleryIndex%gallery.itemCount; //update index
    $('.gallery-img-container').attr("src", gallery.item[galleryIndex].image);
});
```

I appreciate any suggestion, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try listening to `resize` event before moving to a different view. I guess there's a way to `.trigger('resize')`, but honestly I never tried it.

Comment: @Omar, thanks for the reply. Although, resize event doesn't work on touch devices, particularly because when you zoom on touch devices it doesn't change the flow of the document elements like a browser does, so you are not really resizing in the same way a browser resizes.

Comment: I just tested it on iPad (chrome), it fired a few times then stopped. Modern browsers fire `resize` on zooming. I'll keep on testing it.

Comment: I just tested in on iPad safari, and iPhone safari, never fired once. It shouldn't. It fires on non-touch device zoom. I'm surprised it fired on iPad chrome... However, this doesn't seem like a robust enough solution to be used in production.

Comment: Could you please post your viewport meta tag?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>` ...I tried disabling zoom using viewport, but thats not good b/c it disables the entire page. So I removed the viewport tag entirely.